# Coded UI test on RDP

Tags: coded-ui-tests, rdp

I need to record the RDP connection from local machine thru coded ui testing framework (Visual Studio - coded ui project).

FYI. I have Coded UI test project in my local machine and as soon as i start recording I'm going to click on Remote desktop connection and it needs to be recorded.

Comment: If it doesn't support RDP connection record, is there a way to record it?

Comment: Please help us guys to get the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I've played once with such a thing. Coded UI does not support RDP. There's no known way I've heard that you can just record actions inside of remote desktop.

If you really need to do something with Remote Desktop, you may try using [OpenCv Library](http://opencv.org/) to visually identify screen coordinates of your controls. I've done it once. The algorithm is:

- make a screenshot of UI control you want to click on;
- save it inside your Coded UI project;
- pass the image to the OpenCV library when the control is present on screen;
- OpenCV returns you coordinates' rectangle of the control;
- Perform `Mouse.Click();` inside the rectangle.

If you are ready to go with such a solution and need more information, please let me know...

Comment: Thanks for your reply Alex, we want to record the activities which we're expecting to perform inside the remote desktop also needs to be recorded. Alex is there a way to do that? it would be better if you can provide any opensource tool to record such scenarios. Thanks!

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, Coded UI does not support RDP. That's why you cannot identify UI objects and record actions inside RDP window. What do you particularly want to do inside RDP? Wouldn't it better just to launch tests inside this remote machine you try to interact with?